# Delete Result input if both values from other inputs are not in it

Tags: javascript, html

Please edit the title if you have something better. I couldn't think of a good way to say this. In short, I have two form field values going to a `resultCell` element.

This works, but I also need it to delete the result text completely if it doesn't have both values of `cellInput` and `cellSelection` in it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='cellInput'/>
<select id='cellSelection'>
 <option value='@tmomail.next'>TMobile</option>
 <option value='@vzwireless.com'>Verizon</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id='resultCell'>
```

Javascript

```
 var cellIn = document.getElementById('cellInput');
 var dropdown = document.getElementById('cellSelection');
 var textbook = document.getElementById('resultCell');
 dropdown.addEventListener('change', function(){
                           textbook.value = cellIn.value + dropdown.value;
                          });
```

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: No, @ScottMarcus

Just a regular index.html

Comment: What's this, then: `@tmomail.next`? Just regular strings?

Comment: It's the value that the TMobile option tag will have when it's clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check the length of the input and ensure that it isn't 0 before
you produce the result. Since your dropdown has statically set values, you don't need to worry about it.

Also, if you intend to do math with the two inputted values, you'll have to parse the numbers from the inputs (with `parseInt()` and/or `parseFloat()`) because all data is strings in HTML. If you don't do this, you'll get concatenation, instead of addition.

Lastly, your result cell is currently an `input` element, but that's not necessary if all you want to do is display the result. In fact, it's better that it not be an `input` because it disallows the user from changing it.

```js
var cellIn = document.getElementById('cellInput');
var dropdown = document.getElementById('cellSelection');
var textbook = document.getElementById('resultCell');
 
dropdown.addEventListener('change', function(){
   
   // Always reset the result area
   textbook.textContent = "";

   // Always call trim on text fields to remove accidentally added
   // leading or trailing spaces. Once trimmed, you can check the
   // length of the result and if it is greater than 0, there is input.
   var val1 = cellIn.value.trim();

   if(val1.length > 0){
     textbook.textContent = val1 + dropdown.value;
   } 
});
```

```css
#resultCell {
  border:1px solid grey;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  display:inline-block;
  width:250px;
  height:1em;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='cellInput'/>
<select id='cellSelection'>
 <option value='@tmomail.next'>TMobile</option>
 <option value='@vzwireless.com'>Verizon</option>
</select>
<span id='resultCell'></span>
```

But, a better user experience would be to only enable the drop down when the first input field contains data. It's always better to prevent the user from doing the wrong thing, rather than fixing the UI to respond to when the user does the wrong thing.

```js
var cellIn = document.getElementById('cellInput');
var dropdown = document.getElementById('cellSelection');
var textbook = document.getElementById('resultCell');
 
dropdown.addEventListener('change', function(){
   
   // Always reset the result area
   textbook.textContent = "";

   // Always call trim on text fields to remove accidentally added
   // leading or trailing spaces. Once trimmed, you can check the
   // length of the result and if it is greater than 0, there is input.
   var val1 = cellIn.value.trim();

   if(val1.length > 0){
     textbook.textContent = val1 + dropdown.value;
   } 
});

// Enable/disable the dropdown based on whether the input has any data
cellIn.addEventListener("input", function(){
   // Always reset the result area
   textbook.textContent = "";

  dropdown.disabled = this.value ? false : true;
});
```

```css
#resultCell {
  border:1px solid grey;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  display:inline-block;
  width:250px;
  height:1em;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='cellInput'>
<select id='cellSelection' disabled="disabled">
 <option value='@tmomail.next'>TMobile</option>
 <option value='@vzwireless.com'>Verizon</option>
</select>
<span id='resultCell'></span>
```

Comment: The result line does not get erased if only one area is answered.

Comment: @I'mjustacoderforfun Ok, easy enough to fix. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Oh yes, that would be a great idea! My issue is the dropdown, not the input for the phone number. If I could disable it all together until the user puts the phone number, that would solve everything.

Comment: @I'mjustacoderforfun See my updated answer. I just added that code.

Comment: Scott, my friend! You are the bees knees! This is perfect. I switched .textContent to .value. That seemed to work a bit better for me. I thank you!

Comment: @I'mjustacoderforfun The reason `value` works for you is because you still have the "result" area as an `input` (which is where `value` is used) and I have it as a `span` (which doesn't use `value`, but does use `.textContent`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
....
if(cellIn.value && dropdown.value){
    textbook.value = cellIn.value + dropdown.value;
}else{
    textbook.value = "";
}
....
```

Or the short version:

```
 textbook.value = (cellIn.value && dropdown.value) ? (cellIn.value + dropdown.value) : "";
```